# Using both cell editing and row editing in PrimeNG

Tags: primeng, primeng-table

I've been trying to find an answer for some time now and I can't seem to find anything regarding using both options. Has anyone tried and succeeded using both?

I have a small p-table that is using row editing at the moment (when clicking the edit button, another component pops up), but there's an instance where I need to edit a single cell right in the main table.

Apologies if the question is too basic and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a StackBlitz demo for this in the documentation. The [example in the documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/table/edit) doesn't have this dual edit mode but the [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableedit-demo) does.

I've isolated the demo you need [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableedit-demo-xmtuvb?file=src/app/app.component.html) (The original demo contains two demos in one).